# itfoxtec-identity-saml2 .net framework 4.6 web forms guidance

Tags: webforms, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I have an ASP.Net webforms application targeting 4.6.2.  I assume it's possible to convert said application into an SP using itfoxtec-identity-saml2 but I don't see any notes on how to achieve this.

Could anyone provide some guidance on this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is not a .NET WebForms sample. Maybe you can convert a [sample](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test).