# Incorporate WebForms Application with Azure AD for SAML based SSO authentication

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am trying to incorporate ITFoxtec SAML with my webforms applications and Azure AD for SAML based SSO authentication. Can anyone please provide me any reference link or guide me regarding this to work?

**Target Framework: .NET Framework 4.8(Web forms)**

I have gone through the samples given in the github repo but still unable to proceed further.[https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that there is not a .NET WebForms sample but it is possible to implement ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0 in a .NET WebForms application.

Please se the following links:

- [ITfoxtec SAML 2.0 and .NET ASPX application (not MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67011417/itfoxtec-saml-2-0-and-net-aspx-application-not-mvc)
- [itfoxtec-identity-saml2 .net framework 4.6 web forms guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67903371/itfoxtec-identity-saml2-net-framework-4-6-web-forms-guidance)
- [ITfoxtec SAML 2.0 and ASP.NET Web Forms (ASPX) HttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70735069/itfoxtec-saml-2-0-and-asp-net-web-forms-aspx-httprequest)

Alternatively, you can connect to Azure AD using OpenID Connect or use [FoxIDs](https://www.foxids.com/docs) as an security broker to concert between the Azure AD SAML 2.0 connection and your application using OpenID Connect.